# Snake Game in JavaScript: 2 Bugs Occuring

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have 2 bugs that are infecting my game. Here's a link to what I have so far: http://jaminweb.com/Snake.html. Use arrow keys to control the direction of the snake.

Bugs:

- (1) Sometimes the program doesn't register when the snake's head hits its food. I'll have to move over the food several times, from different directions, until it finally works; or sometimes it never works.
- (2) When the snake hits the food, it's supposed to add a link to its end, but for some reason that isn't working.

Relevant code:

```
    $(document).keydown(function(e)
    {
        switch(e.which)
        {
            case 37: // left arrow key
              s.redirect(3);
              break;

            case 38: // up arrow key
              s.redirect(4);
              break;

            case 39: // right arrow key
               s.redirect(1)
               break;

            case 40: // down arrow key
               s.redirect(2);
               break;

            default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
        }
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
     });    

    function snakegame(C, C_h, C_w)
    {
            /* NOTE TO SELF: C is a Raphel object. Can't find a method to return the height
               and width of a Raphael object in the documentation: 
               http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.
               Using C_h and C_w for now, but should probably change it later.
            */

            this.linkSize = 20; // size of a snake unit, in pixels

            this.food = C.rect(Math.floor(Math.random() * C_w / 4), Math.floor(Math.random() * C_h / 4), this.linkSize, this.linkSize);
            this.food.attr("fill","#39275b")

            /* On instantiation, the snake direction is down and has 1 link */
            this.dy = this.linkSize;
            this.dx = 0;
            this.link = C.rect(C_h/2, C_w/2, this.linkSize, this.linkSize);
            this.link.attr("fill", "#d7a900");
            this.body = [this.link];

            /* Event listener for changing the direction of the
               snake with arroy keys on the keyboard
            */
            this.redirect = function(dirnum)
            {
                switch (dirnum)
                {
                    /*
                        dirnum corresponds to
                        1 ---> right
                        2 ---> down
                        3 ---> left
                        4 ---> up
                    */
                    case 1: 
                        this.dx = this.linkSize;
                        this.dy = 0;
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        this.dx = 0;
                        this.dy = this.linkSize;
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        this.dx = -this.linkSize;
                        this.dy = 0;
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        this.dx = 0;
                        this.dy = -this.linkSize;
                        break;

                    default: // never happens
                        break;
                }

            }
            this.move = function()
            {
                /*
                    ..........
                */
                var temp = this.body[0];
                var BBhead = temp.getBBox();
                if (BBhead.x < 0 || BBhead.x2 > C_w || BBhead.y < 0 || BBhead.y2 > C_h)
                {
                    clearInterval(mover); 
                    alert("you hit the wall, idiot!");
                    return;
                }
                var BBfood = this.food.getBBox();
                if (this.boxCollision(BBhead, BBfood))
                {
                    var F = this.food;
                    this.moveFood(BBfood);
                    this.addLink();
                }
                this.body[0].translate(this.dx, this.dy);
                for (var i = 1, j = this.body.length; i < j; ++i)
                {
                    this.body[i] = temp;
                    temp = this.body[i];
                }
            }

            var mover = setInterval(this.move.bind(this), 100);   

            this.addLink = function()
            {
                var lastbb = this.body[this.body.length-1].getBBox();
                var newLink = C.rect(lastbb.x, lastbb.y, this.linkSize, this.linkSize);
                this.move;
                this.body.push(newLink);
                newLink.remove();
            }

            this.moveFood = function(bbf)
            {
                 var tx = Math.floor(Math.random() * C_w - bbf.x);
                 var ty = Math.floor(Math.random() * C_h - bbf.y);
                 for (var i = 0, j = this.body.length; i < j; ++i)
                 {
                    var thisbb = this.body[i].getBBox();
                    if (this.boxCollision(bbf,thisbb))
                        this(bff);
                 }
                 this.food.translate(tx, ty);
            }
            this.boxCollision = function(A, B)
            {
                return A.x >= B.x && A.x <= B.x2 && A.y >= B.y && A.y <= B.y2;
            }

    }
```

which uses this http://raphaeljs.com/ library to create graphic elements.

I'm particularly troubled by (2). Here's the basic logic I have for adding a link to the snake:

```
  var temp = this.body[0];
  /* ..... */
  this.body[0].translate(this.dx, this.dy); // move the head
  for (var i = 1, j = this.body.length; i < j; ++i)
  {
      this.body[i] = temp;
      temp = this.body[i];
  }
```

The intended procedure is:

- Set a temporary variable equal to the head of the snake.
- Move the head of the snake in the direction it's pointed
- Move the element after the head, call it element 2, to the head's previous position. Then move element 3 to element 2's previous position. Etcetera.

Any insight into what the problem is????

Comment: First of all the snake's movement and the food's positions do not seem to fall exactly on the same grid. You need to fix this. Most grid based games use a 2d array of elements to represent game state, and the UI (graphics) is just a rendering of that array.

Comment: Your collision detection seems to be off as a consequence. Also, calling your users an idiot isn't a great idea. Finally, your snake length should probably increase after eating food.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I know my snake's length is supposed to increase after eating food. I've attempted to implement that in problem (2).

Comment: As mentioned by cherouvim, you should use a simple grid (array). So your collision test with the food items becomes `A.x == B.x && A.y == B.y`. Not doing it that way makes things a lot more complicated.

Comment: You can consider the snake as a linked-list, where movement is done on the head, while each `node.move()` will call `next.move(this.previousLocation)`

Comment: To answer 2: The link is added to the body, but it is overlaying the head. Compare `s.body[0].realPath` and `s.body[1].realPath`, they're the same.

Comment: When moving a snake, do this: 1. Set the head's new position, Additional tip: *don't* clear the previous position yet when the snake moves. 2. When the new position contains food, increase a number (`L`) that indicates the snake's length. 3. Compare the actual snake's actual length (`A`) with `L`. 4. Only if `L` is larger then `A`, you clear the previous position. You can see an example implementation [here](https://github.com/blaise-io/xssnake/blob/master/shared/snake.js).